# How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?

Tags: ssh

Let's say I launch a bunch of processes from a ssh session. Is it possible to terminate the ssh session while keeping those processes running on the remote machine?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-close-a-terminal-without-killing-the-command-running-in-it

Comment: To anyone who found this post: please be aware that all of the solutions may not work if systemd is set to kill user processes on logout. See `KillUserProcesses` in `man logind.conf`.

Answer (score 1122, accepted):

You should look for modern alternatives like `tmux`.

`tmux` is superior to `screen` for many reasons, here are just some examples:

- Windows can be moved between session and even linked to multiple sessions
- Windows can be split horizontally and vertically into panes
- Support for UTF-8 and 256 colour terminals
- Sessions can be controlled from the shell without the need to enter a session

## Basic Functionality

To get the same functionality as explained in the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/8657/53508) recommending `screen`, you would need to do the following:

- ssh into the remote machine
- start `tmux` by typing `tmux` into the shell
- start the process you want inside the started `tmux` session
- leave/detach the `tmux` session by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> and then <kbd>d</kbd>

You can now safely log off from the remote machine, your process will keep running inside `tmux`. When you come back again and want to check the status of your process you can use `tmux attach` to attach to your `tmux` session.

If you want to have multiple sessions running side-by-side, you should name each session using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> and `$`. You can get a list of the currently running sessions using `tmux list-sessions` or simply `tmux ls`, now attach to a running session with command `tmux attach-session -t <session-name>`.

`tmux` can do much more advanced things than handle a single window in a single session. For more information have a look in `man tmux` or [the tmux GitHub page](http://tmux.github.io/). In particular, [here's an FAQ](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ) about the main differences between `screen` and `tmux`.

Comment: Tmux is really the way to go nowadays. GNU Screen is nice, but Tmux gives you much more functionality, like attaching from multiple locations without having to detach. It's awesome.

Comment: @CraigM Use `screen -x -r [screenname]` or `screen -rx` for short if you have only one screen session active. This allows you to attach an existing screen instance.

Comment: This advice helped me with the same problem but I think it includes a typo. I am pretty sure that you need to type `Ctrl-b` and then `d` in order to leave/detach the `tmux` session. Certainly that is the case for the version of `tmux` on my Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I can't give you enough points for this, I share the *unlikeness* for screen and didn't knew this whole new world with tmux.Thanks!

Comment: I made a mistake while following the above instructions. I will share it if anybody might fall into the same mistake: I started tmux in the shell of my own computer instead of the shell of the remote computer. One needs to start tmux in the shell of remote computer.

Comment: I wish that I thought of this before starting to make Sage on my remote system. Now I feel grounded until it completes.

Comment: Screen is now being developed again: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/screen-devel/2014-04/msg00024.html Could you update your answer?

Comment: tmux has this idiot idea that calling free(2) shouldn't actually free memory, which results in long-running tmuxes gradually consuming more ane more memory, whether they actually do anything or not. tmux refuses to fix this last time I checked. Screen supports the last 3 features in your list (I use most of them) and doesn't leak all your memory away.

Comment: Alternatively, run `tmux detach` instead of typing `ctrl-b d`

Comment: can you splut a tmux over SSH? Meaning 1) SSH in, 2) TMUX, 3) split so you now have two effective SSH? I tried ctrl-b split

Comment: I'm being dumb but I can't see what I'm getting wrong, I'm using mobaxterm for my SSH connection, I then launch tmux, and start a firefox window. I then call detach back to the SSH shell. However when I close mobaxterm the ff window is killed. Can someone tell me my stupid error? Thanks

Comment: I use `top` to hold the session. Next time I need session I just exit the top and SSH session keep alive.

Comment: @AndrewMacFie: Does `tmux detach` always work? I tried detaching tmux while running a process,  had no effect while the shortcut detached.

Comment: @user598527 if a process is running and you can't run commands you can create a new tmux window and run the command there

Comment: Do I need to detach my session to ensure the process keeps running? Say I start a session by calling `tmux`, I start a process that takes a long time, and my connection to via SSH closes during the process run. Can I connect back in and `tmux attach` with no issues? Or do I need to detach the session for it to be 'saved'?

Comment: Just confirmed myself, you do not need to detach. I was kicked off the connection before detaching the tmux session, when I logged back in `tmux attach` was all that was necessary to return to my running process

Comment: If your SSH connection disconnects before you leave/detach the tmux session, what happens to the processes that are running inside this tmux session?

Comment: I have been trying all these other terminal solutions, but tmux is really superior!

Answer (score 599):

### Option 1: `nohup`

The best way is often the simplest.

```
nohup long-running-command &
```

It was made specifically for this, it even logs stdout to `nohup.log`.

```
man nohup
```

### Option 2: `bg` + `disown`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> followed by:

```sh
bg
disown -h
```

If you want to "background" already running tasks, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> then run `bg` to put your most recent suspended task to background, allowing it to continue running. `disown` will keep the process running after you log out. The `-h` flag prevents hangup.

---

`screen` and others can do it, but that's not what they're for. I recommend `nohup` for tasks you know you are going to leave behind and `bg` for tasks you're already running and don't want to re-start.

Keep in mind, both are bash specific. If you're not using bash, then the commands could be different.

Comment: I would recommend to do `disown -h`

Comment: interestingly screen and tmux doesn't work for miner, bur nohup works

Comment: `bg` + `disown` didn't work for me. I had a deployment script running I forgot to start inside tmux, and needed to leave early for a meeting. The script continuously outputs progress to the shell. `ctrl+z` stopped the process, returning me to bash. `bg` resumed the process, but it also resumed outputting the status to bash, making it impossible to see what I was typing. However, a `disown` command produced "disown: current: no such job"

Comment: this didn't work for me with `julia myFile.jl` for whatever reason. tmux does and is great.

Comment: I don't think this will work anymore with systemd, since systemd terminates all processes in the user slice (at the Linux control group level) when the user session terminates.  I don't have time to test it or research it right now, but just mentioning this in case anyone runs into it: now you know where to look.

Comment: This worked great for me since i am on a node w/o internet access so couldn't install tmux

Comment: Just to clarify, Option 2 is `bg` + `disown`. `bg` by itself isn't enough. `bg` or `&` might work if you log off your ssh (because default `shopt huponexit=off`), but it won't work if your ssh connection gets dropped unless you `disown`

Comment: From this thread I got understanding to use tmux or nohup <command> & or bg + disown to keep service running through sessions. Just to confirm: are they all equal alternative solutions to keep service alive when ssh connection had dropped? (I use tmux and face with issue and think service death might cause it as one of the options)

Comment: I needed to use `disown -a` instead of `disown -h` on Ubuntu 18; make sure the output of `jobs` is empty after disowning to verify that it's truly disowned.

Comment: Sadly the terminal application I need to run, doesn't work with either of these. :( I wanted to do it as simple as possible, but in the end I had to use `tmux`

Comment: You may have to enable `loginctl enable-linger` when using `nohup`. Depending on your distro, your login session might be killed when e.g. no active ssh connections remain. Then despite `nohup`, your processed might be reaped.
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/loginctl.html

Answer (score 278):

You could do that by using `screen`.

Type `man screen` to find out more or read this [screen man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/screen.1.html).

Simple scenario:

- ssh into your remote box. Type `screen`. Then start the process you want.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. This will "detach" your screen session, but leave your processes running. You can now log out of the remote box.
- If you want to come back later, log on again and type `screen -r` This will "resume" your screen session and you can see the output of your process.

Comment: I will usually name my screen sessions using `screen -S name` to make it easier to connect to the correct one later.

Comment: Personally, I'm working on a box without any package control software.  After spending about half an hour building dependencies for TMUX (which I personally have experience with and like) from source, it became clear that screen was the better and simpler solution for me.  TL;DR: the optimal solution to this problem depends on the use case, the machine, and how much time you have to get set up.  Thanks for this answer :)

Comment: Combination with `screen -S` before leave and `screen -r` when coming back is amazing!

Comment: Thanks for this. This solution worked for me while tmux did not (I use a version of bash for windows while ssh'ing into a linux machine)

Comment: It is also helpful to use `screen -list` to list all active screens when you'd like to resume a screen in the future. You can use `screen -r XXXXX` to resume screen with id XXXXX.

Comment: To kill a screen session, go into that screen ( screen -list will show you all screens running, connect to the one you want to close with screen -r some_id and then Ctrl+C to exit the program running, then type exit to exit the screen. session.

Comment: This worked for me only when I pressed Ctrl+A and Ctrl+D at the same time, not one after the other.

Answer (score 106):

Screen and nohup is the better way, but if you have to detach a process already running without screen or nohup you can run disown command.

> `disown [-ar] [-h] [`*`jobspec`*`… |`*`pid`*`… ]`
>
> Without options, remove each *jobspec* from the table of active jobs. If the `-h` option is given, the job is not removed from the table, but is marked so that SIGHUP is not sent to the job if the shell receives a SIGHUP. If *jobspec* is not present, and neither the `-a` nor the `-r` option is supplied, the current job is used. If no *jobspec* is supplied, the `-a` option means to remove or mark all jobs; the `-r` option without a *jobspec* argument restricts operation to running jobs.

With disown you can close the terminal and get the process running on the machine.

Comment: This is also my favourite way to do it. I frequently use `disown -a && exit`

Comment: Perfect. This is a lovely command and deserves all the upvotes!

Comment: one word of caution, I stopped a running process with Ctrl-Z and didn't start it in the background before calling `disown` and it killed it.

Comment: May crash if it wants to write to the terminal. Redirecting output of a running process isn't as easy. Better to start it properly with nohup.

Comment: This is a good answer, because it directly answers the question. The author of the question asked what to do *after* having already executed a bunch of long running commands. Most of these answers let you know what to do *before* you execute the commands.

Answer (score 91):

I was stuck in a large mv so I wasn't in a position to stop the process, setup screen and then start it again. I managed to exit the SSH session with the process running by essentially doing the following steps:

1. Establish SSH connection: `ssh user@host`
2. Run the desired command to start the process
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to pause the process
4. Run `bg` to put the paused process in the background and resume it.
5. Run `disown [pid]` (process ID is optional, defaults to last process) to disown the process. To get a list of jobs simply type `jobs` before.
6. Exit the SSH session by running `logout`.

Usage of the `disown` command:

```
disown [-ar] [-h] [jobspec ... | pid ... ]
              Without  options,  remove  each jobspec from the table of active
              jobs.  If jobspec is not present, and neither the -a nor the  -r
              option  is  supplied, the current job is used.  If the -h option
              is given, each jobspec is not removed from  the  table,  but  is
              marked  so  that  SIGHUP  is  not  sent  to the job if the shell
              receives a SIGHUP.  If no jobspec is  supplied,  the  -a  option
              means  to  remove or mark all jobs; the -r option without a job‐
              spec argument restricts operation to running jobs.   The  return
              value is 0 unless a jobspec does not specify a valid job.
```

Comment: Built-in's are always my first choice :) THX

Comment: This answer should be marked as right. To install and getting used to screen for solving this problem is exaggerated.

Comment: This is very helpful when you have already started any command and which is being running for long. Terminating and starting it in a TMUX Session will take time

Comment: @tom-brossman: Please watch out for unnecessary edits [like this one](/review/suggested-edits/892205)! If invoked without job specification the `disown` built-in command acts on the most recent background job.

Answer (score 28):

There are two major programs you can use to maintain programs and terminal state over multiple ssh connections. They are screen (the incumbent, but unfortunately unmaintained. Apparently [being actively developed now](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/screen-devel/2014-04/msg00024.html)) and tmux (newer, actively maintained). Byobu is a front end that can run on top of their of these systems and offer additional ubuntu status information. On new installations it will use tmux as a backend, if you have an older installation of byobu and an existing config it will maintain the previous backend, be it screen or tmux.

### Byobu

Byobu can be installed on the computer by doing so in a Debian-based machine:

```
sudo aptitude install byobu
```

Using yum, you do

```
su -c 'yum install byobu'
```

It's also possible to install byobu on other distributions.

### Using byobu

You can start byobu by running `byobu` on the host machine after connecting using ssh.
This will give you a shell that looks like this:

[image: image-byobu]

You can also use Byobu Terminal on a Ubuntu machine with -X option and easily have a perfectly working byobu.

### Usage:

Start byobu by typing `byobu`.

You can press F2 to create a new window within the current session, F3-F4 to switch between the various windows.

The best part about byobu is, you dont have to actually kill the processes running in the terminal to leave the terminal. You can simply send screen/tmux (the skeleton of byobu) to background and resume the next time you come:

- To leave byobu and keeep it running (detach) press F6.
- The next time you come, just do `byobu` and you sholud be back right where you were.

  [image: byobu-detach-attach]

You can also create various byobu sessions by `byobu -S session1` and so on. And you can connect to either of them when you come back.

You can do much more using Byobu. Use it!
Some definitive guides are [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/byobu.html.en), or [here](http://linuxaria.com/howto/screen-byobu?lang=en).

Comment: I tried using byobu from a PuTTY-based session to my Ubuntu box, but I get the status line repeated and scrolling on the display. Although it detached properly wen pressing F6, it was not a useable solution in my setup.

Comment: @jfmessier It's because PuTTY doesn't take ncurses (utf-8 basically) well. It's possible to eliminate this problem by following this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731099/byobu-hard-status-line-scrolls-the-screen-when-updating

Comment: This is awesome! 1. it gives me a colored bash prompt that I cannot seem to enable with bash as my default shell and 2. I get to run 2 bots at the same time and *still* have another terminal to do work on! @SiddharthaRT you deserve an upvote sir!

Answer (score 20):

You cannot do this once the process has started, you need to have set things up before you run a long running job.

You can use [nohup](http://ss64.com/bash/nohup.html) but modern wisdom suggests you use screen or byobu as your login so you can detach and leave things running.

Screen has the advantage that you can detach from one machine and reattach from another which is handy if you want to check on long running processes that run beyond the end of the working day.

There is a reasonable getting started [guide to screen](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/keep-your-ssh-session-running-when-you-disconnect/) here.

[byobu](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/byobu.html) puts an easy to use interface on top of screen with menus etc. It's also the current implementation of screen on newer ubuntu. F2 to start a new terminal F3/F4 to toggle back and forth and F6 to disconnect. Type exit to actually end terminals permanently.

Comment: byobu uses tmux these days..

Comment: "You cannot do this once the process has started, you need to have set things up before you run a long running job." -- no, you can use `disown` to achieve this. See @bassgey's answer

Comment: after struggling to learn screen and tmux....byobu brought tears to my eyes

Comment: `disown` and if needed just `Ctrl-z`, then `bg` to get it of the active terminal and to the background. Then, `disown`.

Answer (score 11):

For a single shell script that I have running over a long period of time, I will login, and run the process in the background using '&'.

Example:

```
/path/to/my/script &
```

I've logged out and disconnected my SSH session. When I log in some time later, the script is still executing as proven by continuous data collection from the script.

Comment: Yes, I would like to know how screen / tmux is better than this simple solution.

Comment: Yes, I can see this on my ubuntu also, but it should not happen in theory. I don't understand why

Comment: @MadsSkjern Because you can't enter any input into the script using this method.

Comment: @MadsSkjern the reason is that if you run processes like this  with `&` if you log out and in to your SSH session, the process will still be *running* however you will not be able to see the *output*of that process (if your script echoed something you won't see it, but if it writes a file the file will be there)

Comment: How to output to some file while keep it running? Should I put the `>` before or after &?

Comment: @AugustinNewton it's `some_cmd > some_file 2>&1 &` see this question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106641/351732

Answer (score 8):

Hey, while I agreed that screen is the most efective option.
You can use vncserver and then start the process on it.

Also if your only interes is to have the process running and no need to take control back of it, and utterly most important you were not aware you will need to close the session and you have the process already running, you are not of luck if you used bash as the shell

First you need to send the process to background by typing Ctrl+Z followed by bg %1 (the number depends on the job number, usually it is 1, but you can easily pull the list using the command jobs)

Finally invoke the command disown (followed by the jobid ... same as with bg command)

This will remove the parent-child relationship between your shell and the process in background, preventing it to die when your shell is terminated.

Comment: This answer is the best! Why is everyone talking about `screen`, the question was posed  post-login event, how to keep the processes running, now after logging in but before starting them. Great answer Jorge, you've really helped me! :)

Comment: Simply `bg` (without `%1`) is often enough, since the default is the current job

Comment: It would be nice to have a comprehensive answer: A priori (setting up in advance): ascii terminal screen (old), tmux (neewer); X windows: vnc (old, still maintained), xpra (newer), with xpra being rootless.  A posterior (persisting after you started): ^Z, disown, ...  But I am too lazy to flesh it out more than this.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to run your command in the background with `&`. Then just write:

```
disown -a
```

Answer (score 4):

You should check out [GNU Screen](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/screen) and see if it helps you. Depending on how you need you application to run in realtime, it may cause more issues than it solves, but at least it will allow you to resume your session as if you never left it.

How to use :

- Use the command `screen` for the first start, scroll through the introduction messages, you should be handed a terminal.
- C-a C-c opens another terminal
- C-a C-k kills a terminal
- You can use C-a C-Space and C-a C-Backspace to cycle through terminals
- C-a C-a is handy if you're mostly using only two terminals
- C-a C-d detachs the current screen session and exits screens. You can then use `screen -r` to resume that session. You can have several detached screen sessions at once, in this case you'll be displayed a list of available sessions.

There are many other options, for example split screens, and also all shortcuts are fully customizable.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest answer...

ctrl+z will suspend the running program

"bg" will run it in the background

Comment: Without disowning the process (with something like `disown` or `nohup`), this will not usually keep the process running after the end of the SSH session.

Comment: On my Ubuntu server, with default setup, it really does keep running!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of :

```
cmd options;
```

Add before `nohup` :

```
nohup cmd options &
```

Then, you will be able to see the console stdout by :

```
tail -f nohup.out
```

Answer (score 0):

While everyone says to use `disown` (the only option you have after you already started the process), `nohup`, or even running the command in `screen`, which is useful if you want to see all the output from the command... I'm a fan of `screen`.. I still have tried most recent mainstream distributions of Linux and simply putting the job in the background and quitting does not cause all the processes that are running to die. There must be a global setting or something. I'm trying this on some pretty old systems (slackware 12) and my test script keeps running until I manually kill it:

```
shell$ cat > test.pl

#!/usr/bin/perl
while(1){
     sleep(1);
}
    shell$ perl ./test.pl &
    shell$ exit
    logout
    shell$ ps aux test.pl
    mymom 31337     1  0 13:25 ?        00:00:00 perl ./test.pl
    shell$
```

While I agree that `screen` would be the best way to run this, even if my script wrote to log files or whatever.. I've never needed to use `disown -a`  or `nohup` unless it was out of complete paranoia. Maybe someone can shed some light on how bash behaves by default? Maybe some system administrators change the defaults on large shells to keep their users' processes from overloading the system?

Comment: If you have any further query please ask it as a [new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)