# Is it possible to continue an ssh session upon each re-connection?

Tags: server, ssh, remote

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session)

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 on a remote server. I'd like to know if it's possible to continue an ssh session upon each re-connection. I intend on running a server-application I wrote which has to be gracefully exited.

I guess I could add a remote restart/stopping of the application but I'd still need the real-time output. Which is why having the ssh session continue upon re-connection would be really useful, if not crucial. Thanks.