# how to recover backgrond process from a killed terminal

Tags: ssh, command-line, process

I have launched a long running process from ssh in background .
Unfortunatly my connexion crashed .
Now I'm trying to recover this process but when I execute fg it didn't detect it .
How can I bring it back to foreground ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 5):

You don't.  Typically such processes are killed when you disconnect, unless they ignore SIGHUP.  If you want to be able to reconnect to long running programs like that, you need to use something like `screen` on the target computer and run the program under the `screen` session, which allows you to disconnect and reconnect.

- [How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session)