# How to check "apt-get upgrade" status after losing ssh connection?

Tags: apt, ssh

Usually I upgrade my Ubuntu installation through a ssh connection. Sometimes this ssh connection would be lost or I would accidentally close the terminal window.

It is possible to check the upgrade status after a ssh re-login into the computer?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The following logs are related to apt upgrades:

```
/var/log/apt/history.log
/var/log/apt/term.log
/var/log/dpkg.log
```

If the command was `dist-upgrade`, there are additional logs in:

```
/var/log/dist-upgrade
```

FYI, it is usually safe to just re-run the upgrade and apt will continue where it left off when the process died due to disconnection.  However...

**A GNU Screen Primer:**

When ssh'ing into a remote server and starting a long-running process in the foreground, it is best practice to use GNU Screen.  Screen provides a virtual terminal that continues running even if your ssh connection is lost.

Install screen:

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

Run screen:

```
screen
```

After running screen you will get a command line prompt as with a normal terminal.  You can then run the upgrade from inside screen:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

To understand how this works, "detach" screen by pressing **Ctrl+a, d**.  This will return you to the non-screen terminal.  You can see the list of running screens with

```
screen -list
```

If you only have one screen running, you can reattach it with:

```
screen -raAd
```

(This detaches screen in case it is attached elsewhere, and reattaches it to the terminal you are currently running.)

Typically you cannot scroll 'normally' from within screen without some extra setup.  To scroll within screen, press **Ctrl-Esc** to enter cursor mode.  You can then scroll down and up with **j** and **k**.  Press **Esc** again to exit cursor mode.

There are many more resources on the net available for additional screen functions.  It is an invaluable standard tool for system administration.

See also:

- [How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session?rq=1)

Comment: +1 voor actually answering the question AND mentioning screen :)

Comment: Also, `screen -x` - attach to running screen without detaching others, making the screen session "multiplayer".

Comment: This is helpful, but includes prevention in addition to the answer.  Moreover, the correct log to look at is cited, but a beginner user might not be familiar with the `tail -f` command and flag option, which will allow the user to observe the progress in real-time (or see that it crashed) upon "re-login."  I know its old and accepted, but I think tail should be added to this instruction set, because in lacking this detail, the answer below by @TheAnonymousBear is more direct and to the point.  @doublerebel

Comment: Often `sudo dpkg --configure -a` will continue to the apt upgrade, when that was still spending.

Answer (score 25):

I had an upgrade in progress (asking me whether to keep or replace a config file; this information I took from `/var/log/apt/term.log`) when my terminal was closed by another person. Restarting `apt upgrade` complained about a lock file being held.

My fix was to do the following:

```
sudo killall apt # to release the lock
sudo dpkg --configure -a # to fix the interrupted upgrade
sudo apt upgrade # to make sure no packages are left not upgraded
```

Comment: Best answer, thanks

Answer (score 22):

To see real-time output from background `apt` job, use:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/apt/term.log
```

Comment: This is the correct answer - the answer above just states the location of some helpful logs then switches to prevention.  This answer shows the user where to look, and how to look at it (`tail`) after what they called a "re-login."

Answer (score 13):

In addition to doublerebel's answer, I noticed an alternative today.

I went to bed last night after starting an upgrade over SSH. I stupidly forgot to start it in `screen` and lost my SSH session overnight.

I was just about to start researching `retty` when I noticed that `root` had started a `screen` session.

```
me@GAMMA:~$ ps aux | grep -E 'release|upgrade|apt'
root      6208  0.0  0.0  29140  1628 ?        Ss   01:57   0:05 SCREEN -e \0\0 -L -c screenrc -S ubuntu-release-upgrade-screen-window /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-1h6_g4/raring --mode=server --frontend=DistUpgradeViewText
root      6209  0.2  5.6 287428 93144 pts/2    Ss+  01:57   3:13 /usr/bin/python /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-1h6_g4/raring --mode=server --frontend=DistUpgradeViewText
root      6239  0.0  0.0  50052  1184 ?        Ss   01:58   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -o PidFile=/var/run/release-upgrader-sshd.pid -p 1022
root      7306  0.0  4.6 287432 77284 pts/2    S+   02:43   0:08 /usr/bin/python /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-1h6_g4/raring --mode=server --frontend=DistUpgradeViewText
me       26829  0.0  0.0   9440   956 pts/5    S+   22:18   0:00 grep --color=auto -E release|upgrade|apt
```

So I listed `root`'s screens and attached to it:

```
me@GAMMA:~$ sudo screen -list
There is a screen on:
        6208.ubuntu-release-upgrade-screen-window       (12/11/2013 01:57:58 AM)        (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-root.
me@GAMMA:~$ sudo screen -x -r
```

And **Bam!** I was back in the game.

Comment: I thought you forgot to start screen.  How was screen running if you "forgot to start in screen?"

Comment: @oemb1905 Because Ubuntu starts one for you, under the assumption that you'll forget :)

Comment: interesting, is this with the `do-release-upgrade` command specific to ubuntu?  I have never had a need to check on Debian, which I use exclusively, because I always run it manually, detach, and then come back.  And, of course, we use `sudo apt dist-upgrade` after changing `/etc/apt/sources.list` instead.

Comment: I found it, yes this is Ubuntu-specific so any pure Debian folks like me that poach fixes from AskUbuntu should not assume this will happen on their systems.  Original thread on this topic:  https://serverfault.com/questions/387547/how-do-i-reattach-to-ubuntu-servers-do-release-upgrade-process#427008

Comment: How does it know you will have screen installed?

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same issue, lost my connection and the dpkg process was waiting for input.

Maybe next time try: `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: When I try this, all I get is, `"dpkg: error: dpkg frontend is locked by another process"`

Comment: I did a context grep to see that thankfully it was a subprocess that generated an message dialog waiting for input, so I was able to just kill that without killing the whole apt upgrade process.

Comment: This approach ignores investigation into whether the dpkg process is still running on the system upon relogin.  Moreover, if it is running, then this could be potentially harmful at worst, or just bad practice at best, since dpkg will have a lock on it in `/var/dpkg/lock` if it is still running.  And regardless, it does not answer the question of how "to check the upgrade status" and, instead, will only work if the upgrade crashed (and only then if the lock is not active).  I would not recommend this approach to anyone.  Respectfully, oemb1905

Comment: Does not answer to the question

Comment: After years of finding this Answer again and reading this comments - you're right! not the recommended way and not answering the question at all!

Answer (score 1):

This post helped me to do better in the future: use 'screens'

This Debian post helped me to fix my acute problem:

https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ

```
sudo fuser -vki -TERM /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend

sudo dpkg --configure --pending
```

Answer (score 0):

*TL;DR: After losing ssh connection you might have an unreachable console dialog blocking your upgrade from continuing. Kill the whiptail process to allow it to continue.*

I had a similar problem and while some of the answers were useful, they didn't help me resolve my problem.  But between @Huckle's answer and @CivMeierFan's 2nd comment on @Sebastian Faujour's answer, I found my way forward.

"ps aux | grep -E 'release|upgrade|apt'" showed a [whiptail](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/whiptail.1.html) process (also shown with "/var/log/apt/term.log", but in that case it just dumped an unusable console prompt. Helpful to understand why the upgrade was blocked, but not helpful for resolving the problem).

Killing the whiptail process allowed the upgrade to continue.

Comment: I tried that, it just got me the next dialog asking something (even the same question, I think).