# How to run a python program in the background even after closing the terminal?

Tags: command-line, process

I am running a python program from a terminal in my Ubuntu machine as,

```
$ python test.py
```

But my whole program will be stopped if I close the terminal, Is there any way of running this python program in the background so that if I close my terminal then it still keeps on running?

And also after running this program in the background, how do I find out my actual program whether it is still running or not if I am logging back again to that terminal?

Comment: See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/106351/running-programs-in-the-background-from-terminal?rq=1 should answer your question. Also a possible duplicate.

Comment: And, when you run a program in the background with `&`, it will print a PID that you can search for with something like `ps aux | grep PID`.

Comment: @Seth Yes, that puts it in the background, but when the terminal is quit, the program goes away too...

Comment: @Seth: Everytime I do need to remember the PID to look for the process?

Comment: @TechGeeky Yes.

Comment: @TechGeeky You might be able to use the name of your program (`test.py`) but the PID is usually more reliable.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Use the shebang line in your `python` script. Make it executable using the command,

```
chmod +x test.py
```

Use no hangup to run the program in the background even if you close your terminal,

```
nohup /path/to/test.py &
```

or simply (without making any change in your program)

```
nohup python /path/to/test.py &
```

Do not forget to use `&`  to put it in the background.

**Role of `nohup`:** `nohup` makes your script ignore [`SIGHUP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP), and redirects [stdout/stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) to a file *nohup.out*, so that the command can continue running in the background after you log out. If you close the shell/terminal or log off, your command is no longer a [child](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_process) of that shell. It belongs to [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) process. If you search in `pstree` you'll see it is now owned by process 1 (init).

To see the process again, use in terminal,

```
ps ax | grep test.py
```

That cannot be brought back to the foreground because the foreground (as the terminal already closed) no longer exists. So there is no way to get that terminal back again once it is closed.

Comment: Great but I guess you should add python after nohup i.e. nohup python /path/to/test.py...

Comment: @Denny both `nohup python /path/to/test.py &` or `nohup /path/to/test.py &` will work. For the latter you need to use the shebang line in your python script and make the script executable as shown above.

Comment: How to bring the script to the foreground?

Comment: @LiXinyang If you are using `bash`, `fg` will bring the script to the foreground. But that won't change the output redirection, which will still be going to `nohup.out`. If the command `jobs` cannot find see it, then it is no longer a child of this shell. If you do a `ps` you'll see it is now owned by process 1 (init). That cannot be "brought back to the foreground" because the foreground no longer exists. you can use `screen` which will enable you to  attach/reattach.

Comment: @souravc I am using `ash` shell in Synology NAS, which does not support `jobs` and `fg`. :( But I can see the script is running using `ps`. I think it is probably better using some other tool like **Tmux**. Thanks for your response and helpful answer.

Comment: `screen` (as @souravc mentions) or `tmux` is what you want : https://askubuntu.com/a/8657/169878 or https://superuser.com/a/632219/47628 . Many more advantages than a nohup.

Comment: How would one close the task once it is opened in the background?

Comment: The program usually ends on its own after doing some specific task, or you may close the program using any of the program's quitting options. Else, you have to kill it from `pstree`.

Answer (score 17):

```
python test.py &
```

will run the file in the background.

In order to find the running program, you can use `ps -e` to list all running programs. You can use `grep` to find your particular program from the list.

Comment: In this case program will be terminated if you close the terminal, but OP do not want it.

Comment: @souravc Nope, the program will become a child of `init --user`. At least if you use the gnome terminal. Therefore it will only terminate upon logging out.