# how to leave a process running in backgroun on a terminal

Tags: command-line, ssh, emacs

I am running some simulation through a server.

I usually login in the server using ssh command from the shell of my laptop. 
then I run emacs in terminal mode and with it I start some python simulations.

Now I would like to close the connection between my laptop and the server but leave the simulations and emacs running in the server.

I would like then be able to connect again to the server and restart to work with emacs.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried http://askubuntu.com/questions/106351/running-programs-in-the-background-from-terminal ?

Comment: I do not think that this will work because I am running my application inside the terminal.

Comment: So, you have a emacs server in the server?

Comment: I think that it is the standard emacs. You can obtain a similar result if you run emacs -nw in the terminal

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to detach the processes from your terminal and leave them running in the background but there would be no way to reattach them later.

To achieve what you describe, you would need to use screen, tmux or a similar tool that allows reconnecting.

See [How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session)