# What is the status of GNU screen?

Tags: tmux, gnu-screen

Two answers in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session) state that `screen` is unmaintained. However, the GNU repository of `screen` shows an upload this year after 6 years, and 14.04 has two newer versions than the earlier Ubuntu releases (one in the main release, and one in `backports`, from 14.10). Unmaintained software get dropped from Ubuntu, but `screen` remained even after a six-year period of inactivity. So what is the status of `screen` in general, and in Ubuntu? Will it remain (reasonably) maintained, or should I switch to `tmux` or other alternatives?

Comment: I looked at the GNU screen home page and there was no mention that the project was unmaintained. In addition, as you say, there was a release this year. I suggest you ask on their mailing list.

Comment: I think there was a fork of screen called Byobu which was easy to customize.

Comment: Unless you have lots of customizations, use tmux anyway. At the very least, use it for a day or two and figure out if you like it enough to invest in migrating your configuration over.

Comment: @Paul byobu isn't a fork but a frontend to multiplexers, I think.

Comment: To close voter(s): I am not looking for a recommendation based on quality, features, etc., but on something that can be determined as a fact: Is `screen` maintained or not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Amadeusz Sławiński**, GNU Screen’s new primary upstream maintainer uploaded 2 versions this year:

- [the status quo of Screen development as version 4.2.0](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/screen-devel/2014-04/msg00024.html)
- the [4.2.1](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/screen-devel/2014-04/msg00074.html) that you can find in the [Ubuntu repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-backports/screen)

From the 4.2.0 announcement:

> With this I also plan to put v.4 into maintenance mode and start
>   developing v.5 with cleaned up source code, new features

Clearly the project is not unmaintained, but as many other projects it requires contributors to fix bugs and work on new features.

Sources:

- [GNU Screen 4.2.0 in Debian Experimental](http://noone.org/blog/English/Computer/Debian/GNU%20Screen%204.2.0%20in%20Debian%20Experimental.html)
- http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/screen

Comment: I wondered if the releases were a "Ok, we're shutting up shop, but here are some bug fixes."-style closing-up clearance. If the maintainer is new and plans to start developing new versions, that's great news.