# Remote login program and disconnect

Tags: remote-access, remote-login

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'm trying to run a program in remote login, and then disconnect whereas the program is running. More specifically:

I have a Matlab program which ends with the command save, so that I save some images a .mat files. For that I use the following commands:

```
rlogin (name)
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay <file.m
```

And when file.m finishes, the last command is a save, so that a keep the required data in the computer where I'm logged. However, the program takes around two hours, and it is very common that I lose the connection before it finishes. So I wanted to find the way to send the command, and keep it running even if I lose the connection, so that the data are automatically saved when it finishes, and I can recover it when I use remote login again.

Thanks!

Comment: This is the [classical task for `screen`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen). See a tutorial here: http://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session) (It's the same with an `rlogin` or a `telnet` --- the fact that the answer is about `ssh` is immaterial).