# Run command on remote server over SSH - without exiting

Tags: networking, bash, ssh, remote

I connect to my school's Linux Lab frequently to work on my programming assignments remotely. Sometimes, when there are lots of other students logged in to the server, the connection is slow, and I lose work during connection timeouts. There are several servers to choose from in the lab, and I want to be able to automatically run `who` as soon as the connection is made, so I can see how crowded the server is, and use another one if it's pretty full. Right now, I use a function in my .bash_aliases file to streamline the connection and password entry:

In file `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# ssh to the Linux lab. Takes hostnames defined in ~/.ssh/config as 
# parameters
function sshll()
{
    if [ "$@" ]
      echo "Connecting to hostname $@";
      sshpass -f <password_file> ssh $@;
    else
      echo "Connecting to default host";
      sshpass -f <password_file> ssh <user@ipaddress>;
    fi
}
```

This works, so I added `who` to the end of the `ssh` commands:

In file `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# ssh to the linux lab. Takes hostnames defined in ~/.ssh/config as 
# parameters
function sshll()
{
    if [ "$@" ]
      echo "Connecting to hostname $@";
      sshpass -f <password_file> ssh $@ 'who';
    else
      echo "Connecting to default host";
      sshpass -f <password_file> ssh <user@ipaddress> 'who';
    fi
}
```

This connects, enters my password automatically, and runs `who`, but then closes the connection. **Is there a way I can run `who` automatically, without closing the connection afterward?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session)

Comment: This question is related to, but definitely not a duplicate of that question. I'm asking how to run `who` automatically upon connection without closing the connection; not how to leave it running after disconnection. That would be useless in this situation, where I just want to see some output every time I connect remotely, without having to type it every time.

Comment: Is your goal to keep session alive to run more  commands , or just hold session to view output of one command that runs long time ? In first case, if server is crowded , you can log out right away and try different one, but if not crowded, continue working.

Comment: I want to hold the session open to run more commands. Just passing `who` with ssh shows the output, but kills the session.

Comment: I see . . . . So basically an init command is what you want . . . .without editing any rc file on client

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**: int_ua's answer is the way to go, simplest and effortless.

**Why this works the way it does**

This goes back to the basic behavior of any shell. When you login simply as `ssh user@server.domain.whatever` you get interactive version of the shell. When you run `ssh user@some.server.net -t "command1;command2"` you basically get `/bin/sh -c 'command1;command2'`. The first one lets you run whatever you put into the `stdin` while sourcing  the dot files, while second just executes those commands and exits. Essentially, there is no way to run a command before interactive use ( unless it is in one of the dot files ) or get an interactive shell from the single-shot command `sh -c` (or whichever shell it may be, not necessarily `sh` ).

**Failed or incomplete ideas**

My first idea I had is this : if the shell uses server's local `.bashrc` , could one make it use client's local file on the server ? [Well,no](https://stackoverflow.com/a/764954/3701431). Not unless you [copy the dot file over to remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/765554/3701431) with scp or rsync.

Second idea that i had is the `PROMPT_COMMAND`. This very nice `bash` variable runs command each time before showing your `PS1` prompt, so why not set this variable before  spawining `bash` to `PROMPT_COMMAND="who; unset PROMPT_COMMAND"` so that we run it as single-shot?

Problem is this variable has to be exported to the remote server, and [Gilles answer](https://superuser.com/a/163228/418028) helped me to do something like this:

```
ssh -o SendEnv=PS1 ssh localhost -t bash
```

or

```
ssh localhost -t " PROMPT_COMMAND='who; unset PROMPT_COMMAND' bash  "
```

Problem ? -o option SendEnv must allow that specific variable that you are trying to send in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` , and besides in either case you still get to run all that stuff with `/bin/sh -c`

**Slight improvement to int_ua's answer**

So by now we can see that `ssh user@server -t 'command1;shell'` pattern works the best. Except there is one minor nitpick: `/bin/sh -c` process is still there , so why not run `bash` with `exec` to replace that process out?

```
 ssh user@server.net -t 'who;exec bash'
```

Comment: I chose this as the answer, because (1) it improves on the other answers (if only slightly), and (2) it explains *why* it works, which is always more helpful than just a line of code or a *what*. I can't award the bounty until later today, but this answer has earned it.

Comment: Yes, `exec` is a really nice improvement, thank you.

Comment: One with `PROMPT_COMMAND` seems to be only solution if you want run command in remote shell - for example use `alias`

Answer (score 5):

Just executing `bash` should be enough:

```
 sshpass -f <password_file> ssh <user@ipaddress> 'who; bash';
```

Comment: How will executing `bash` give me the output of `who`...?

Comment: bash simply will not clear the terminal history (at least by default), so you should see all the previous lines. AFAIU these lines will not be available for some automatic handling, but it shouldn't be a problem in your case. Also, if you use plain `ssh` you will have to use `-t` key.

Comment: Oh, maybe you've seen the first revision of the answer where I've forgot to add the `who`, is that the case?

Comment: Yes, that was the case. It makes more sense now. How would using the -t flag help?

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann Without `-t`, SSH won't allocate a TTY, and interactive programs like shells, editors, etc. will behave *very* weirdly (or fail altogether). (You'd also want to run `bash -l` for `.profile` to take effect.)

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann sorry, I thought I was quick enough to edit it :)

Comment: @muru s/With -t/Without -t/, right?

Comment: @int_ua yep, corrected. :)

Comment: That's pretty much what would be used with either ssh or local terminal. Basic idea is `command; shell` or `shell -c ' command1;commad2` ; shell ` . Good answer

Answer (score 3):

This is *an* answer, but definitely not *the* answer.

I discovered that `sshd` (the daemon for ssh services on the remote host) will run commands in ~/.ssh/rc upon connection. I just created this file, and added `who` there, and now a list of users is displayed every time I make a remote connection, and I still get a login shell.

On remote host:

```
File ~/.ssh/rc:

#!/bin/bash

# This file is executed by sshd when a remote connection is started over ssh
who
```

On client:

```
In file ~/.bash_aliases:

#!/bin/bash

# ssh to the linux lab. Takes hostnames defined in ~/.ssh/config as 
# parameters
function sshll()
{
    if [ "$@" ]
      echo "Connecting to hostname $@";
      sshpass -f <password_file> ssh $@;
    else
      echo "Connecting to default host";
      sshpass -f <password_file> ssh <user@ipaddress>;
    fi
}
```

I am still interested in knowing how to do this from the client side, however, for other users with similar problems who can't use ~/.ssh/rc for lack of permissions, or whatever other reason.

Answer (score 3):

[int_ua's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/737244/158442) is what I'd use. Just for completeness, if you can edit your own `.profile` or `.bashrc` on the remote server, you could append this to either one:

```
if [[ -n $SSH_TTY ]]
then
    who
fi
```

SSH sets various variables, one of which is `SSH_TTY` - you can test for these variables to determine if you're connected via SSH. Restrictions on `~/.ssh/rc` should not prevent you from using this.

---

I use this to set my prompt (note how I skip the hostname for local shells):

```
if [[ -n $SSH_TTY ]]
then
    PS1="\u@\h:\w \$ "
else
    PS1="\u:\w \$ "
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I wonder why nobody mentioned `expect`, that seems to be just designed for such cases. (Of course, you need to install the `expect` package first).

```
!#/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh user@host
expect "assword:"
send "mypassword\r"
expect "$ "
send "who\r"
interact
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want ssh and execute commands without exiting:

**Method 1**

```
ssh  -t USER@SERVER "command1; command2;bash --rcfile ~user/.bashrc"
```

OR

**Method 2**

```
ssh -t USER@SERVER "$( cat <<'EOT'
COMMANDS
bash --rcfile ~user/.bashrc
EOT
)"
```

Sending variables to commands in Method One:

```
var1="Hello World"
var2="Salam World"
ssh  -t USER@SERVER "echo $var1; echo $var2; command3;bash --rcfile ~user/.bashrc"
```

Works fine

I recommend use Method One and call stored shell in server and send needed variables to that:

```
ssh  -t USER@SERVER "bash /path/to/server/stored/script.sh $var1 $var2 $other_var;bash --rcfile ~user/.bashrc"
```