# Connecting to existing terminal from iPhone to Ubunutu desktop

Tags: networking, server, ssh, minecraft, iphone

I run a small Minecraft server on an Ubuntu PC in my house. Sometimes I have to manage the server outside of my home so I use an ssh client on my phone. This works, but each time I close the app and then relaunch I have to create a new terminal session. How can I toggle to the existing one?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you install and keep `screen` running. It's a terminal multiplexer, in other words - terminal session splitter.

You have to have `multiuser` mode enabled to that you can attach to that session. So inside the terminal on the server, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> , then immediately <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>. The bottom of the screen will highlight and you will see a semicolon there. Type in `multiuser on`.

Now, from another computer you can SSH into your server, and type in `screen -ls` to know the title of the session. Example:

```
xieerqi:$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        4704.pts-5.eagle        (11/24/2015 01:23:04 AM)        (Multi, attached)
```

Type in `screen -x sessionTitle` to attach. Example:

```
screen -x 4704.pts-5.eagle
```

Now you're back to the existing session.

To detach, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, followed by <kbd>d</kbd>

Comment: I ended up using tmux, but thank you!