# How to save from broken pipe?

Tags: server, internet

How to save from `broken pipe` from Internet connection ? Suppose I am doing some crucial work on remote server then how to save life from doing that ? At least save my work before breaking connection . Can any one figure it out ow to do it ? My remote server has Ubuntu 16.04 operating system.

Comment: See [How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session)

Answer (score 2):

You could and should run crucial work on the remote server in a multiplexer like [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) or [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).