# Execute java from terminal and let it run even after the ssh session ends

Tags: command-line, ssh, java

i'm using a java application on my terminal wich listen to a specific port for specific connections .

i'm using it in terminal like :

```
java -jar Server.jar
```

everything works perfectly except that when i disconnect from the ssh session ( using putty ) , the connection get lost and the server stops .

i want to let the connection or the server open even after ending the ssh session .

Comment: Have you tried `nohup java -jar Server.jar &`?

Answer (score 6):

Answer is in top 1 related question

[How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session?rq=1)

`nohup java -jar Server.jar &`

Comment: Please use **flag** > **duplicate** next time.

Comment: Cannot with my reputation