# Figuring out if gcc make was successful

Tags: software-installation, ssh, gcc, make, makefile

I am a very inexperienced Ubuntu user. I am using a computer cluster at my university via SSH. The cluster has a version of gcc that was too old for something else that I needed to install, and I am trying to install an updated version of it just in my user space. I am trying to install version 4.9.4, while the cluster has 4.4.7. I do not have sudo privileges, and cannot use apt-get. I am following instructions from the [official gcc page](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC) (which was also explained in [this blog post](http://luiarthur.github.io/gccinstall) I found).

The gcc page says that the `make` step could take a very long time, so I left it running overnight. At some point, I think my connection was interrupted, because today morning, my terminal said "Broken pipeline". This is the last thing that was shown from the `make` command to the terminal on my laptop:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/nfs/thry/drpv/Gowri/Software/objdir'
make[3]: Entering directory `/nfs/thry/drpv/Gowri/Software/objdir'
rm -f stage_current
make[3]: Leaving directory `/nfs/thry/drpv/Gowri/Software/objdir'
Comparing stages 2 and 3
warning: gcc/cc1-checksum.o differs
warning: gcc/cc1plus-checksum.o differs
```

I would expect that even if my ssh connection was interrupted, the command that I typed in on the cluster computers should finish running. Am I wrong in assuming that?

I decided to go ahead and try `make install` anyway, and after a few minutes of running (and showing a bunch of steps on screen), I got this:

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/nfs/thry/drpv/Gowri/Software/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common'
Makefile:373: .deps/sanitizer_allocator.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:374: .deps/sanitizer_common.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:375: .deps/sanitizer_common_libcdep.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:376: .deps/sanitizer_coverage.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:377: .deps/sanitizer_flags.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:378: .deps/sanitizer_libc.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:379: .deps/sanitizer_libignore.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:380: .deps/sanitizer_linux.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:381: .deps/sanitizer_linux_libcdep.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:382: .deps/sanitizer_mac.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:383: .deps/sanitizer_platform_limits_linux.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:384: .deps/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:385: .deps/sanitizer_posix.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:386: .deps/sanitizer_posix_libcdep.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:387: .deps/sanitizer_printf.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:388: .deps/sanitizer_stackdepot.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:389: .deps/sanitizer_stacktrace.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:390: .deps/sanitizer_stacktrace_libcdep.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:391: .deps/sanitizer_stoptheworld_linux_libcdep.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:392: .deps/sanitizer_suppressions.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:393: .deps/sanitizer_symbolizer.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:394: .deps/sanitizer_symbolizer_libbacktrace.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:395: .deps/sanitizer_symbolizer_libcdep.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:396: .deps/sanitizer_symbolizer_posix_libcdep.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:397: .deps/sanitizer_symbolizer_win.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:398: .deps/sanitizer_thread_registry.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:399: .deps/sanitizer_win.Plo: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** No rule to make target `.deps/sanitizer_win.Plo'.  Stop.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/nfs/thry/drpv/Gowri/Software/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common'
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nfs/thry/drpv/Gowri/Software/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libsanitizer'
make[1]: *** [install-target-libsanitizer] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nfs/thry/drpv/Gowri/Software/objdir'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Does this mean that the install did not work properly, and I should try to redo the `make`? I would like to avoid the long wait time if possible, but I can redo it if necessary. Apologies for the rather long question and thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like your `gcc` download is incomlplete. Did you read and follow all the `README*`, `INSTALL*`, etc files?

Comment: The README file referred me to the webpage that I linked in my question. I followed the steps written there. I am not sure how I could be missing files from the download, since I got the tar file directly from one of the mirror sites mentioned on the official website. Could files be missing if the `make` didn't work properly?

Comment: One of the main jobs of `make` is to figure out what targets are not up to date - so probably the simplest way to find out whether it completed successfully is to run it again and look for a `make: '<progname>' is up to date.` message

Comment: Can I run make again without uninstalling/removing any files? Does it just figure out what else needs to be done?

Comment: If you want to run a remote job or keep a shell session throughout disconnections (deliberate or forced) you should look into terminal multiplexers and session managers like `tmux` or `screen`. That would also allow you to check the exit status of long running commands and see (at least the last few lines of) their output.

Comment: I am using `screen` now, thanks! I ran `make` again and was able to install.

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect your output for later perusal:

```
make <options> 2>&1 | tee make.out;  echo status $?
```

But I think the broken ssh link will stop it from completing.  If that is a problem, use something like mosh.  Mosh will let you reconnect a broken  session even if you loose all connectivity, hibernate, change APs, etc.

Comment: after rereading your original question - I see you may not be able to install mosh of the server - you could try using screen for a similar capability.
Here are some other suggestions: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session]

Comment: Thank you for all the info! Normally when I need to submit jobs to the cluster, I use qsub. I suppose for installing software, this isn't really helpful? And do you think I should restart the make? If yes, do I need to throw out both the gcc folder and the objdir folder before I do it? I ask because untarring itself took some time.