# If I SSH into a server via terminal and start a process to copy files, is it killed after I log out?

Tags: ssh

And if so, can it be kept alive somehow?

(This is not a duplicate question since I did not know that logging out will kill a process. Maybe others also don't and so ask the wrong question.

I would suggest that the answers include a link to the other [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session).)

Comment: I think the other question is very important but please keep in mind that you have to already KNOW, that a process will be terminated if you log out of ssh. I did not know this and this one answer is made it very clear and gave a clear, short solution.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware of that. Good point. -- Btw, if you are satisfied with the answer below you may follow the advice given in [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers). ;-) But please don't feel pushed. Just take your time.

Comment: I will test the answer and mark it as such if it works.

Comment: What do you mean “SSH into a samba share”? It’s either an SSH server offering services via the SSH protocol or a Samba server offering services/resources via the CIFS protocol. You can’t use SSH to access a CIFS resource.

Comment: I am SSHing into a server that is also providing a samba share. You are right, the fact that this server also provides a service via CIFS is not important. I will change the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the process will get a "Hangup" signal (`SIGHUP`), which is not usually caught, and results in process termination. Read `man -a signal` and the `man` pages it points to.

The `nohup` command was designed to overcome this difficulty, without the overhead of `screen` or `tmux` (`nohup` was invented first, back when "Hangup" referred to modems). You can specify a logfile, or let `nohup` save `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to `./nohup.out`, if possible, or `$HOME/nohup.out` if not.

```
nohup command >$HOME/command.log &
```

Comment: Why is th & necessary at the end? If I would use for example "nohup cp -v &" is there a way to log out of SSH and back in and then get the output from -v by re-connecting to the process?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, commands you have started will be stopped if you log out.
But you can start them using the `screen` command:

```
$ screen command
```

From this virtual screen you can exit afterwards (`Ctrl+A, D`), while letting the command proceed running.

You can start a command and instantly send it into a virtual detached screen as well:

```
$ screen -fa -d -m command
```

To get an overview of your screen sessions, use the following command:

```
$ screen -list
There are screens on:
    2457.pts-2.myserver (22.10.2018 20:04:35)   (Detached)
    12596.pts-3.myserver    (28.08.2018 22:10:00)   (Detached)
    4632..myserver  (15.07.2018 20:56:55)   (Detached)
3 Sockets in /run/screen/S-me.
$
```

Bring a session back in foreground, using the `-r` switch, while giving the session id:

```
$ screen -r 2457.pts-2.myserver
```

Comment: In your first answer you said something about re-connecting to the process. That would be interesting, e.g. if I use "screen cp -v" and then log out of SSH and back in later.

Comment: I did a little research myself and I would suggest you add "screen -r" and "screen -ls" to your answer.

Comment: I added a description of the other two arguments