# screen session killed on logout 18.04

Tags: 18.04, screen, logout

I want to keep an application running in the background when I log out.

That was working flawlessly with screen, but since today for some unknown reason the screen session is killed when I log out.

Any ideas?

Comment: Lots of ideas - but what troubleshooting have you done? What changes have you made?

Comment: I tried all of this
https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session
and all of this:
https://www.tecmint.com/run-linux-command-process-in-background-detach-process/
nothing worked. It seems as if the os is killing the processes I create

Comment: well, to me it seems that it is related to this:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=825394

Answer (score 0):

If you need a "quick fix" and you currently can not use screen. Have a look at tmux.

Not a great solution, but it might just help you for the moment.

Comment: actually I went a completely different way now - Docker! It's far from optimal as it is quite some overhead to set up a docker container, but it works, thx...