# Running a process through SSH command and keeping it alive

Tags: server, ssh, python, nohup

I try running a python program on a remote server using nohup as explained in:
[How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session)

When I do `ssh server -C "nohup prog.py &"`, the python program exists with `BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`.

When I do `ssh server -C "nohup prog.py"`, the python program runs smoothly, but the ssh connection obviously stays alive. Once I `ctrl^c` it, I get the `Broken pipe` error again.

Obviously I'm missing something here, but no idea what.

Comment: Is the program writing output to stdout/stderr? If so did you try to reroute that to file or /dev/null?

Answer (score 0):

Like xenoid pointed out in the comment, redirecting the stdout/stderr to anywhere other than the screen fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try GNU Screen (`ssh server -t "screen python prog.py"`).
Screen will protect the process from dying. Use `^A` then `d` to detach and `screen -xr` to reattach.