# Detach celery session from tmux?

Tags: ssh

I am not able to detach from tmux after running celery process by pressing ctrl+D or ctrl+B as mentioned in this answer
[How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session?newreg=2ee193d52abf47ef89550bfc869e1c33)

and command I am using for celery is
**celery -A portal.celery_example.celery worker --loglevel=INFO**

Comment: my os is linux ubuntu 20.04

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to detach". Can you open the tmux command mode (default to `ctrl+b` followed by `:`), and type the command: `detach`?

Comment: @ArturMeinild, the shortcut is `ctrl+b`  followed by `d`.

Comment: I know - I just wanted to see if the OP could detach manually by typing in the command in command mode.

Comment: Because if yes, then the problem is not that he can't detach, but maybe the problem is his keyboard shortcuts - which is another matter.

Comment: @jack for future reference, here are the default tmux shortcuts: https://tmuxcheatsheet.com/