# How to resume a process after loosing ssh session?

Tags: command-line, ssh, suspend, process, resume

There are some questions for keeping a linux process on a remote PC, running after loosing ssh session.

1. [How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session)
2. [How can I keep a process alive after closing the putty session?](https://superuser.com/questions/96660/how-can-i-keep-a-process-alive-after-closing-the-putty-session)

But unfortunately, I accidently lost my ssh session on Windows Putty without any prior screen or nohup configuration. Is there a way to resume that lost ssh terminal process?

Comment: It is like you lost your wallet. It is gone.

Comment: @user68186 but you found the wallet so I expect to get it back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain your session and contents during disconnection there are a number of options.   My personal recommendation is tux..

https://linuxhandbook.com/tmux/

Think of it as a text/ncurses based window manager.  It runs in the background and if you disconnect or your connection drops you can reattach to the session and it will be exactly how you left it.

e.g. (To start a new session)

```
tmux new-session
```

e.g. (To list existing sessions)

```
tmux ls
```

e.g. (To attach to an existing session)

```
tmux attach
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello the way i know is you can use the command in screen sessions so even if you get disconnected you can still connect to it. I use it to run my minecraft server.
and i can connect to it again with the following command

`screen -r server`
simple right?

Comment: This was already mentioned in one of the answers to [How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](https://askubuntu.com/q/8653/) which was linked to in the question.