# Run bash script in a separated process (dettached from SSH/Putty)

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm accessing Ubuntu Server from a putty terminal and then I run this `test.sh` script from that terminal:

`$ bash test.sh &` *(note the **&**)*

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do

    node myscript.js

    wait $!
    sleep 5

done
```

Which is supposed to keep that node script running "forever". The issue is that when I close the SSH session/remote terminal (Putty) the script is also terminated.

How do I keep that script running after closing that SSH session?

Comment: Use `screen` or `tmux`. You'll love it ;-)

Comment: With your specific method you're missing `disown` or `nohup` (https://askubuntu.com/a/8672/158442, https://askubuntu.com/a/222855/158442, other answers too)

Answer (score 0):

Use `crontab -e` and add your file there. Search how to use crontab to determine how to setup the correct timing. crontab is used to run scripts every X minutes/hours/days or even on specific dates (every 5th day of the month at 7 pm). It will run the script in the background for you.