# How to keep the ssh session process running even after been disconnected

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I am connected to a remote computer by using ssh connection. I am using jupyter notebook to train a neural network model. The process will take days to finish. I want to keep the process running even after I am disconnected. I know that tmux and screen can do that for me but i have a problem

so the way i connect is from windows

```
ssh Ipaddress
```

Then I connect to the Jupyter notebook. This gives me a URL address to open the  notebook.This is happening in a single command prompt.

Now the problem is that i have to write this line,in a separate command prompt.

```
ssh -NL portnumber:localhost:portnumber host@IP
```

And when I turn my computer off this connection is cut which makes the process stop running.Is there a work around with this

Comment: You need something like screen (`apt install screen`). A session manager, that will held the session, even if the connection is lost. Start your connection, type 'screen' ... play around ... disconnect your session, reconnect and reattach with `screen -x`. You'll get the console as you left it - There are other, like tmux, byobu, mtm ... But I don't know them well. Just use what feels good to you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session)

Comment: @ArturMeinild i already saw that question my problem is i have to run two ssh as you can see in my question

Comment: Please clarify which machines are involved, what is running where, the exact sequence of commands you use to set it all up, which machine you want to turn off and what you want to continue running. Keep in mind that nothing can run on a turned off machine.